# If all corporate (large scale) networks require routers

Tags: routing, router

Wondering if all large-scale networks *require* routers or if there are other devices or things that are used in practice in some corporations *instead* of routers that solve the same or similar problems as they do. Trying to get a sense of the various types of equipment and how the features work and are implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, routers are required if the network exceeds a certain size.

You could build a network on a switched (or bridged) basis, essentially everything in a single, large L2 segment (broadcast domain). The efficiency of such a structure slowly decreases with size (since broadcasts are propagated within the entire domain), so there's a practical, maximum size, depending on your requirements.

Also, if your network needs Internet connectivity you require a router. You cannot bridge to the Internet.

Comment: Wondering if they need to be _physical_ routers, or if they can be virtual routers on a server.

Comment: For the network, there's no difference between physical and virtual routers. You use whatever suits your purpose better.